# Compiling C++ with OpenSSL on Windows using g++: cannot find -lssl and -lcrypto

Tags: c++, openssl, g++, mingw

I'm trying to compile a c++ file with g++ on windows11 that have this included:

```cpp
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
```

I installed the OpenSSL from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html like lot of guides said.

I tried to run the command like this:

`g++ -o wifi wifi.cpp -I"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include" -L"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib" -lssl -lcrypto`

but I keep getting this error:

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto`

I checked inside the OpenSSL files and I see the files libssl.dll and libcrypto.dll so the files are actually downloaded but mingw dosent find them.

Comment: Try using forward slash, `/` to separate directories.  Windows will accept the forward slas as a directory separator.

Comment: Does the "32" in `mingw32" compatible with the 64 in `OpenSSl-Win64`?  IMHO, they should both be 32 or 64.  Try passing the 32-bit libraries path of OpenSSL to the compiler.

Comment: Your task would be easier if you switched to use msys2 to install the current MinGW (with gcc-13.2) and use `pacman` in msys2 to install compatible openssl libraries: [https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-openssl](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-openssl)

Comment: I will try with it. Also no, mingw32 didnt affect that because i just installed openssl 32-bit and i still get the same error

Comment: linking directly against dlls is a fairly new mingw feature, I'm not sure your old version supports that, you'll need to use `.lib` files